# How to update the release specific dependency automatically in Jenkins with Maven as Build Tools

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, maven-plugin, jenkins-groovy

We have a maven project producing the jar as artifact(Let Say Module-1).
We are maintaining multiple branch for this project.
This jar is used inside the mulitple other maven project as dependency which is also build via maven (Let Say Module-2,Module-3 ...and so on).

Right Now we are updating the dependency manually in POM of dependent Module(2,3,4...etc) , whenever we have the latest build of module-1

we are using jenkins file to build all the project.

Branching and versioning strategy is same for both the project.

Both Core module and dependent module can have the Multiple Branch.

I want to automate this process of updating jar version (Module-1) in the pom of the project(Module-2,3,4...) using it as dependency as soon as we update this maven project(Module-1) producing the jar artifact to all the dependent war file.

Along with one constraint, if I update branch-A of Module-1 then only branch-A of Module-2,3,4.... should be updated with the latest version of Module-1 from branch-A .....and similarly for the other branches.

Do we have any way to achieve this?

Technology Used
Build Tool : Maven
SCM : Mercurial
CI/CD Jenkins